# If $n = 4k + 1$, does $4$ divide $n^2 -1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How would I show that $4$ divides $n^2 -1$ if $n = 4k+1$?

Is there more than one way to solve this?

Comment: If you're not familiar with modular arithmetic, just plug in $n=4k+1$ and expand the square, and rewrite the answer in the form $4m+r$, hopefully with $r=0$.

Comment: HINT: $n^2-1=(4k+1)^2-1$.

Comment: $$4k + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$$ Then, $(4k  + 1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ finally,

$$(4k + 1)^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$

Comment: Yes there is more than one way: try induction.

Comment: I think it's important to note that it's true only if $k$ is an integer, which isn't specified here; so there's a chance this is a trick question, the answer to which would be "it depends". (Yes, i know about the discrete math tag, but that's probably just from OP getting this question in the context of a DM course)

Answer (score 4):

$$n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)=(4k+2)4k=4p$$
with $p=k(4k+2)$.

Answer (score 3):

if $n=4k+1$ then $n^2-1 = (4k+1)(4k+1)-1 = 16k^2 + 8k + 1 -1 = 16k^2 + 8k=4(4k^2 + 2k)$

Now clearly $4$ divides $4(4k^2 + 2k)$

Because $4k^2 + 2k$ is an integer , call it $m$

and so it is even more clear now that $4$ divides $4m$

and so $4$ does divide $n^2 -1$.

Comment: How do we know that $4k^2+2k$ is an integer? Wouldn't that assume that $k$ is an integer in the first place, which isn't specificed?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff

it is discrete mathematics so it must be an integer :D  Just kidding

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different ways of proving it, and I feel like even if I was the first to respond to you today, I would still be repeating what others have said (in response to questions similar to yours).

Although proof by contradiction is a valuable tool, it's kind of overkill here, in my opinion. The second most direct way is with simple algebraic rewriting. If $n = 4k + 1$, then $$n^2 = (4k + 1)^2 = (4k + 1)(4k + 1) = 16k^2 + 8k + 1.$$ It follows that $$\frac{n^2 - 1}{4} = \frac{16k^2 + 8k + \require{cancel}\color{red}{\cancel{1}} - \color{red}{\cancel{1}}}{4} = 4k^2 + 2k.$$ 
But the most direct way takes advantage of congruences, which I don't know if you've been taught yet. If $n = 4k + 1$, then $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Therefore $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ also, obviously leading to $n^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Comment: If you right click on the equation, then select Show Math As TeX Commands, you can see how I introduced the cancellations you wished to include.  See this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for additional information about the use of colors and crossing things out.

Comment: Thank you very much, @N.F.Taussig.

Answer (score 1):

For $k = 0$, $n = 1$, $n^2-1 = 0 = 4\cdot 0$.

Assume statement is true for some $k = h$. Let $(4h+1)^2-1 = 4a$.

For $k = h+1$, 
$$\begin{align*}
(4h+5)^2 - 1 &= (4 + 4h+1)^2 - 1\\
&= 4^2 + 2\cdot4(4h+1) +(4h+1)^2-1\\
&= 4^2 + 2\cdot4(4h+1) + 4a
\end{align*}$$
which is divisible by $4$.

Similarly for $k=h-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$n = 4k + 1$, prove, $4 | n^2 - 1$.

If $k$ is an integer, $n$ will always be an odd number.

Suppose $4$ does not divide $n^2 - 1$.

$$n^2 \equiv a + 1 \pmod{4}$$

For some remainder $a \ne 0$

Because $n$ is odd,

$$n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$$

Thus,

$$0 \equiv a \ne 0 \pmod{4}$$

Which is clearly false as $0 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ for any $n \ne 0$.